# How to fix Module not found: Can't resolve '@heroicons/react/solid' in react app?

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I am following this brilliant [post](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/build-portfolio-website-react/) to learn react. However, some essential bits are missing.

When I open the app in the browser I get the error

> ./src/components/Navbar.js
> Module not found: Can't resolve '@heroicons/react/solid'

Apparently, I am missing a module. I tried to install it but nothing helped so far.

I tried:

```
npm install heroicons-react

npm install @react-icons/all-files --save

npm install @iconify/icons-heroicons-solid

npm install @heroicons/vue
```

The folder structure looks like:

```
project
|
|-package.json
|-node_modules
|-homepage
  |-node_modules
  |-package_json
  |-src
  |-public
  |-README.md
```

I tried the to execute the commands in the project directory and the homepage directory. Not sure which one I should use.

The code in question in Navbar.js looks like:

```
import { ArrowRightIcon } from "@heroicons/react/solid";
```

Comment: Try `npm install @heroicons/react`

Comment: Does it matter where I execute that  command?

Comment: In the root of your project

Comment: That worked. Looks quite obvious retrospectively.

Comment: I always does in the end :)

Answer (score 24):

This will resolve you problem.

```
npm i @heroicons/react
```

Answer (score 18):

For anyone recently having trouble, you need to:

```
import {} from '@heroicons/react/24/outline'
```

24 or 20 are the original sizes of icon as specified on heroicons site

Comment: The maintainers pushed out a big update recently, so adding the size fixes the issue. Thanks for your concise reminder!

Comment: This is the only solution that works for me in a React/Next 13 project.

All other solutions here are citing the documentation but the documentation does not seem correct/updated for TypeScript

Answer (score 10):

My friends, if you want to use **heroicons** **V2** with **TypeScript**, just make sure that you are using the right path, just like the below:

```
import {UserIcon, Bars3Icon} from "@heroicons/react/24/solid"
```

There are **24** and **20** folders inside the **@heroicons/react/**, for TypeScript, you should use those folders.

Answer (score 9):

This question is already resolved and I just wanted to add a few more things for newcomers. [heroicons](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/heroicons) have clear documentation on GitHub.

**React:**
First, install `@heroicons/react` from npm:

```
npm install @heroicons/react
```

Now each icon can be imported individually as a React component:

```
import { BeakerIcon } from '@heroicons/react/solid'

function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BeakerIcon className="h-5 w-5 text-blue-500"/>
      <p>...</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Vue**
Note that this library currently only supports Vue 3.

First, install `@heroicons/vue` from npm:

```
npm install @heroicons/vue
```

Now each icon can be imported individually as a Vue component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <BeakerIcon class="h-5 w-5 text-blue-500"/>
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { BeakerIcon } from '@heroicons/vue/solid'

export default {
  components: { BeakerIcon }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't work for Typescript

Comment: They are in the @heroicons/react/solid and @heroicons/react/outline folders. Importing specific folder item should work in TypeScript :)

Comment: I ended up using *react-icons*, but I will take tah into account. Thanks !!

Comment: @Jose4Linux try this for typescript: '@heroicons/react/24/outline'. 24 or 20 are the original sizes of icon as specified on heroicons site.

Answer (score 7):

Downgrade to 1.0.6 solved it for me

```
yarn add @heroicons/react@1.0.6
```

Answer (score 5):

Maintainers has released an update recently and  it's messing up the imports used in previous version. I wish they could make the release a bit more easier to adapt on consumer side.

Anyway, you now need to define the sizes too in the import statements.

Previous Version import:

> import {} from '@heroicons/react/outline'

> import {} from '@heroicons/react/solid'

Latest version import:

> import {} from '@heroicons/react/24/outline'

> import {} from '@heroicons/react/20/solid'

Answer (score 4):

It could be because the installed version is v2 heroicons. Try installing heroiconsv1.

```
npm install heroicons-react
```

Comment: for installing v1  `npm i heroicons/react@v1`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue when installing `@heroicons/react` on  nextjs, managed to resolve the issue by installing the module as a devDependencies.

Install it as below:

```
npm i -D  @heroicons/react
```

This will fix the module and the type error when using the modules

`@heroicons/react/24/outline` and
`@heroicons/react/20/solid`.

Comment: Works for me.. on nextjs13

Comment: thank you -- this helped me on nextjs too

Answer (score 1):

After installing with:

`npm install @heroicons/react`

use

`npm audit fix --force`

Answer (score 1):

test this command `npm install heroicons-react`
or add

```
"@hookform/resolvers": "^0.1.0"
```

to your package.json

Answer (score 1):

If your codebase imports directly from @heroicons/react/solid, you are probably trying to import from Heroicons v1, but you have Heroicons v2 installed.

Use this cmd:

```
npm install @heroicons/react@v1
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the @heroicons/react package is installed. You can do this by running the following command in your terminal:

```
npm install @heroicons/react
```

Answer (score 1):

you can find icon names for react to add in {} here:

https://unpkg.com/browse/@heroicons/react@2.0.18/24/outline/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35404323)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have newer version (2) but you need v1. just happened to me just now. I had to uninstall v2 and use

npm install @heroicons/react@v1

this worked for me.

Comment: @MohammadFarhadi nailed it above, it's easy to migrate to version 2, don't be lazy just add 20 or 24.

read the docs, v2 explains breaking changes

Answer (score 0):

If you are coding in React, You only need to install React library. @heroicons/vue is specific to vue framework and others libraries are also unnecessary.

Run this command at the root of your project

```
npm install @heroicons/react
```

Now, in your Navbar.js import ArrowRightIcon. There are two versions 24 and 20.

24 is standard `24*24` icons.
20 is mini `20*20`

```
import { ArrowRightIcon } from "@heroicons/react/24/solid";
```

Answer (score 0):

`npm i @heroicons/react --legacy-peer-deps`

If all other methods fail, use this it will definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

Do these steps and it will fix the issue, I believe the thread is quite old so the answers are not updated with latest updates on the dependency -

Install Heroicons Package: Run the following command to add the Heroicons library to your project:

```
npm install @heroicons/react
```

For Yarn

```
yarn add @heroicons/react

# Step 1: Navigate to your projects directory

cd path/to/your/homepage

# Step 2: Install the required Heroicons package

npm install @heroicons/react

# Note: After installation, ensure your import statement in Navbar.js looks like this:

import { ArrowRightIcon } from "@heroicons/react/24/solid";

# Step 4: Restart your development server to apply changes

npm start

OR 

yarn start
```

Hope this answer helps